# Can tflite model implementation on FPGA

Tags: fpga, tensorflow-lite

I want to quantize the ssd-mobilenet model , then implementation on FPGA，
now i use the ssd_mobilenet_v1_quantized_coco model http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/ssd_mobilenet_v1_quantized_300x300_coco14_sync_2018_07_18.tar.gz
,then convert .pb file to .tflite file ,then can i use the tflite model on FPGA?

Comment: After training tflite model with post training quantization and viewing the model using Netron, i figured out that some first layers are still in float! Which indeed needs multiple FPGA kernels to be implemented which is not efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Currently Tensorflow only Supports android, ios and microcontrollers.
as you need to synthese Hardware blocks in FPGA, you need to write inference of you network manually in c++ or rtl.

Comment: That's what I am trying to do, but can not get the calculations implemented correctly. Could you please take a look at my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59118407/calculation-operations-with-the-parameters-of-a-tflite-quantized-model)